# binary safe write on file with php to create a DBF file

Tags: php, dbf

I need to split a big DBF file using php functions, this means that i have for example 1000 records, i have to create 2 files with 500 records each.

I do not have any dbase extension available nor i can install it so i have to work with basic php functions. Using basic `fread` function i'm able to correctly read and parse the file, but when i try to write a new dbf i have some problems.

As i have understood, the DBF file is structured in a 2 line file: the first line contains file info, header info and it's in binary. The second line contains the data and it's plain text. So i thought to simply write a new binary file replicating the first line and manually adding the first records in the first file, the other records in the other file.

That's the code i use to parse the file and it works nicely

```
    $fdbf = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],'r');
    $fields = array();
    $buf = fread($fdbf,32);
    $header=unpack( "VRecordCount/vFirstRecord/vRecordLength", substr($buf,4,8));
    $goon = true;
    $unpackString='';
    while ($goon && !feof($fdbf)) { // read fields:
        $buf = fread($fdbf,32);
        if (substr($buf,0,1)==chr(13)) {$goon=false;} // end of field list
        else {
            $field=unpack( "a11fieldname/A1fieldtype/Voffset/Cfieldlen/Cfielddec", substr($buf,0,18));
            
            $unpackString.="A$field[fieldlen]$field[fieldname]/";
            array_push($fields, $field);
        }
    }
    fseek($fdbf, 0);
    $first_line = fread($fdbf, $header['FirstRecord']+1);
    
    fseek($fdbf, $header['FirstRecord']+1); // move back to the start of the first record (after the field definitions)
```

`first_line` is the variable the contains the header data, but when i try to write it in a new file something wrong happens and the row isn't written exactly as it was read. That's the code i use for writing:

```
$handle_log = fopen($new_filename, "wb");
fwrite($handle_log, $first_line, strlen($first_line) );
fwrite($handle_log, $string );
fclose($handle_log);
```

I've tried to add the `b` value to `fopen` `mode` parameter as suggested to open it in a binary way, i've also taken a suggestion to add exactly the length of the string to avoid the stripes of some characters but unsuccessfully since all the files written are not correctly in DBF format. What can i do to achieve my goal?

Comment: Can you not use a DBF library because there isn't one, or is there some arbitrary reason why you have to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I have no control on the webserver, i cannot install new extensions and the provider doesn't allow me to do it

Comment: If you write your own php, why not just include a DBF library in YOUR code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As i have understood, the DBF file is structured in a 2 line file: the
>   first line contains file info, header info and it's in binary. The
>   second line contains the data and it's plain text.

Well, it's a bit more complicated than that.

See [here](http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm) for a full description of the dbf file format.

So it would be best if you could use a library to read and write the dbf files.

If you really need to do this yourself, here are the most important parts:

- Dbf is a binary file format, so you have to **read and write it as binary**. For example the number of records is stored in a 32 bit integer, which can contain zero bytes.
- You **can't use string functions on that binary data**. For example `strlen()` will scan the data up to the first null byte, which is present in that 32 bit integer, and will return the wrong value.
- If you split the file (the records), you'll have to adjust the record count in the header.
- When splitting the records keep in mind that each record is preceded by an extra byte, a space `0x20` if the record is not deleted, an asterisk `0x2A` if the record is deleted. (for example, if you have 4 fields of 10 bytes, the length of each record will be 41) - that value is also available in the header: `bytes 10-11 - 16-bit number - Number of bytes in the record. (Least significant byte first)`
- The file could end with the end-of-file marker `0x1A`, so you'll have to check for that as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So i really need a DBF library, the issue is not on the php fwrite function. Thanks

Comment: @TizianoMischi I think your main (first) problem is in `strlen($first_line)` which will return the wrong value. If you fix that and change the recordcount value in the header, you should probably be fine. You also don't have to read each field definition, just copy the whole header and change the recordcount. The length of the header is in bytes 8-9.