# SQLite3::exec(): unrecognized token: "'Date"

Tags: php, sqlite

I get the error message `SQLite3::exec(): unrecognized token: "'Date"` when I insert a command into a SQLite database.
If I have the SQL commands echoed and execute them via the console, this also works. The data for this comes from a dbase database.
If I enter a string for fieldname the insert commands will work.

```
$field=unpack( "a11fieldname/A1fieldtype/Voffset/Cfieldlen/Cfielddec", substr($buf,0,18));
$db = new SQLite3('databases/test.db');
$sqlCode .= "INSERT INTO HEADER (name) VALUES ('".$field['fieldname']."');";
$db-> exec($sqlCode);
```

Comment: What exactly does `$field['fieldname']` look like? Also, I find it's easier to get all the quotes lined up right (which I think you have) with variable interpolation instead of concatenation: `$sqlCode .= "INSERT INTO HEADER (name) VALUES ('{$field['fieldname']}');";`

Answer (score 0):

Would be that much easy to use prepare satement against sql injections

> If I enter a string for fieldname the insert commands will work

make sure if fieldname is a text value

I am using pdo :

```
$sqlCode = "INSERT INTO header VALUES (:name)";
$query = $db->prepare($sqlCode);
$query->bindValue(':name', $field['fieldname'], SQLITE3_TEXT);   

$result = $query->execute();
```

**EDIT :** Error says unrecognized token **Date**, So, if fieldname is a date you might need to change `SQLITE3_TEXT` to `SQLITE3_BLOB` OR `SQLITE3_INTEGER` **Usualy not needed**.

But you need to insert date into `date` column not into `name` column

**EDIT 2 :**
it's a bit complicated.

See [here for a full description](http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm) of the dbf file format.
So it would be best if you could use a library to read and write the dbf files.

If you really need to do this yourself, here are the most important parts:

- Dbf is a binary file format, so you have to **read and write it as binary**. For example the number of records is stored in a 32 bit integer, which can contain zero bytes.
- You **can't use string functions on that binary data**. For example `strlen()` will scan the data up to the first null byte, which is present in that 32 bit integer, and will return the wrong value.
- If you split the file (the records), you'll have to adjust the record count in the header.
- When splitting the records keep in mind that each record is preceded by an extra byte, a space `0x20` if the record is not deleted, an asterisk `0x2A` if the record is deleted. (for example, if you have 4 fields of 10 bytes, the length of each record will be 41) - that value is also available in the header: `bytes 10-11 - 16-bit number - Number of bytes in the record. (Least significant byte first)`
- The file could end with the end-of-file marker `0x1A`, so you'll have to check for that as well.

See asked : [binary safe write on file with php to create a DBF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628785/binary-safe-write-on-file-with-php-to-create-a-dbf-file/50892312#50892312)

**Final Word** : you need DBF library
[Data File Header Structure](http://www.dbase.com/KnowledgeBase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm)

Comment: [SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: @Luuk thanks for clearify, I knew that it was adding date as a text, but wasnt sure cause I didnt use it for years, that is why I said you might and commented **usualy not**. I will edit

Comment: Date is the string stored in fieldname. 
In the error message, **'** is before the string Date. But I don't know where that comes from.

Comment: @NilsThiele Can you share html form part ? edit your question

Comment: The data comes from a dbase database.



`function getHeader($dbfname) {
    $fdbf = fopen($dbfname,'r');
    $fields = array();
    $buf = fread($fdbf,32);

    $goon = true;
    $unpackString='';
    $sqlCode = '';
    while ($goon && !feof($fdbf)) { // read fields:
        $buf = fread($fdbf,32);
        if (substr($buf,0,1)==chr(13)) {$goon=false;} // end of field list
        else {

         //Feld-Namen holen
            $field=unpack( "a11fieldname/A1fieldtype/Voffset/Cfieldlen/Cfielddec", substr($buf,0,18));`

Comment: Begin of Database:

yDateDHourNMinuteNSecondNPlantNoNErrorNmr101A0Nmr101A1Nmr101A2Nmr101A13Nmr101A14Nmr101A15Nmr101A16Nmr101A17Nmr101A18Nmr101A19Nmr101A20Nmr101A21Nmr101A22Nmr101A27Nmr101A28Nmr101A29Nmr101A30Nmr101A31Nmr101A36Nmr101A38Nmr101A54Nmr101A63Nmr101A64Nmr101A65Nmr101A66N
 2019030100011530000000000000000000000000 2019030100020132537272726161517525369696612151025252511253453 2019030100030152334292929171717555571656615171229293210243350 2019030100140152535282829166616495066697714171229282711263350 20190301001501421332828271616175146676766141612302626102

Comment: @NilsThiele where this `$field['fieldname'];` come from ?

Comment: @Dilek `$field=unpack( "a11fieldname/A1fieldtype/Voffset/Cfieldlen/Cfielddec", substr($buf,0,18));`

Comment: Thanks :)
I'll have to find a library. 
You wouldn't happen to know of one, would you? :D

Comment: @NilsThiele I tried to use this one a long time ago, http://dans-dbf-lib.sourceforge.net but must be more arround. sorry! you didnt have full codes in answer that is why it tooks me long time to figure out its a dbf :)